# Qt Can't Draw At Android Emulator

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-emulator

I am currently trying to create a basic application to Android with Qt C++ and I am using Qt Creator. I want to make a design that looks like a radar screen with black background and green circles.

I have done every steps of installations about Android and Qt 5.11.1.

I am creating this application for armeabi-v7a so my kit is that too.

I have written the code that makes the background black and I have drawn 3 green circles on that. My code works just fine for Desktop Qt 5.11.1 MinGW 32 bit kit. the output is like this:

[image]

But when I change the kit to open up the Android Emulator for armeabi-v7a, this happens:

[image]

Now there is something that I don't know exactly. My background has been changed to black but I can't see any circles. I know that my background isi changed because if I don't use the the function that I have written to change the background to black, this happens in windows kit:

[image]

And this happens in arm kit:

[image]

My paintEvent function to draw ellipses is like this:

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    QPainter painterObj(this);
    painterObj.setPen(QPen(Qt::green, 2, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap));

    painterObj.save();
    painterObj.drawEllipse(0, 0, 318, 512);
    painterObj.restore();

    painterObj.save();
    painterObj.drawEllipse(53, 86, 212, 340);
    painterObj.restore();

    painterObj.save();
    painterObj.drawEllipse(106, 172, 106, 168);
    painterObj.restore();
}
```

My background color changer function is like this and I call it right after ui->setupUi(this); :

```
void MainWindow::setBackGroundColorToBlack() {
    QPalette pal = palette();

    // set black background
    pal.setColor(QPalette::Background, Qt::black);
    this->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    this->setPalette(pal);
}
```

These functions are under protected at header file like this:

```
protected:
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e);
void setBackGroundColorToBlack();
```

Can anyone please help me? I am stuck with this problem and I can not find any guide or answer on the internet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just changed the paintEvent like this:

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
setUpdatesEnabled(false);
QPainter painterObj;
painterObj.begin(this);
painterObj.setPen(QPen(Qt::green, 2, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap));
painterObj.drawEllipse(0, 0, 318, 456);
painterObj.drawEllipse(53, 76, 212, 304);

painterObj.drawEllipse(106, 152, 106, 152);

painterObj.end();
```

}

And added a `update();` statement at the end of setBackGroundToBlack() function. And now it is drawing at the emulator too.